# Angular 8 - Access to value of a promise object

Tags: angular, promise

I want to access to the result of a promise. I got a service "archivosService.getJerarquiaUsuario", that returns a JSON that is called from http.

This is my component code:

```
  llamarATestearPromise(){
    const result = this.testearPromise();
    console.log('Resultado de testearPromise : ' + result );  
  }

testearPromise(){
    console.log ('testearPromise: ' + this.archivosService.getJerarquiaUsuario(1));
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
this.archivosService.getJerarquiaUsuario(1)
    .toPromise()
    .then(
    res=>{
        console.log('resssss: ' + res['jerarquia'].USUARIO);
        resolve( res['jerarquia'].USUARIO );
    },
    msg => {
        reject('Error al obtener la jerarquía del usuario');
    }
    )
});

return promise;
```

}

I want to access to res['jerarquia'].USUARIO from llamarATestearPromise method
How i can make that?

Comment: just as a tip. Yo hablo espanol but the majority of the people here don't. Try to write your code in english if possible and don't use promises, use observables to make your angular app more reactive :)

Answer (score -1):

Where do you want the access to that field?
Plus I think Angular recommends the use of RxJS rather than raw promises.